# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.supportsSourceType(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-autoconfiguration

I have written a spring application.

In the main method I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.supportsSourceType(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
at org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.supportsSourceType(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:79)
at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.supportsEvent(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:282)
at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:214)
at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
at com.visa.redis.Application.main(Application.java:27)
```

Following is my Application class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.test")
public class Application {
static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    SeperateRead seperateRead = applicationContext.getBean(SeperateRead.class);

    try {
        seperateRead.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Following is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>redis-client</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshots-repo</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
            <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

I looked at the possible causes for this error over internet, looks like some version mismatch. But I am not able to figure out the problem.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use @SpringBootApplication?